# 'Client' object has no attribute '_deletetouch' in django admin logout section

Tags: python, django, memcached

I am unable to logout the user in admin panel of Django. The logout task is not perform after using memcached code in Django settings file. It shows an error like:

> 'AttributeError at /admin/logout/'

and

> 'Client' object has no attribute '_deletetouch'.

The memcached code in settings.py as:

```
enter code here
SESSION_ENGINE='django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you used in LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL?

Comment: I don't write any login or logout code. I am using inbuilt admin panel.

Comment: LOGOUT url also works for inbuilt admin panel

Comment: @Karthik while using logout button in admin saction it show an error

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this recently and found that I had python3-memcached installed (which is deprecated), and needed python-memcached instead. The reason it showed recently is because django 3.1 has a change which calls an undocumented method in memcached - questionable decision - but it works fine with the regular memcached versions.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone got stock in this again, I've tested recent versions of python-memcached, found recently updated versions, which is 1.60 and 1.61 would cause this. So I rolled back to 1.59 and solve the problem.